# Can I run code *after* a built-in wxWidgets event is handled?

Tags: c++, event-handling, wxwidgets

I suspect there must be a built-in way to do this, but my Google-fu has failed me.

I'm using a `wxScrolledWindow`, and I have to paint an *unscrolled* background picture behind the contents each time the window is scrolled. I've made a scroll handler like this...

```
void homewindow_t::onScroll(wxScrollEvent &evt) {
    Refresh();
    evt.Skip();
}
```

...which works to force it to redraw the entire window each time. Unfortunately, it draws the window *before* the scroll is handled, so the background is repainted and then scrolled up or down, screwing up the alignment. The documentation suggests that `Refresh` just invalidates the screen, meaning that the scroll handler must be forcing a redraw.

The only way around this that I can see is to handle the scrolling code myself, which I'd rather not do if I don't have to.

Ideas, suggestions, clues...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only general solution I've found to running code after an event is handled is to post a second, different event to the event queue before skipping the current event (so that it gets handled by the default handler), and handle that when it comes up.

However, perusing the wxWidgets source code, I've found an answer to my specific problem: there's a function, `wxScrolledWindow::EnableScrolling`. Although it's not obvious from the name, this will enable or disable the "physical scrolling," which is what forces the instant redraw. So calling `EnableScrolling(false, false);` in the window's constructor solves the issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

To paint a "fixed" background in `wxScrolledWindow` you should just offset the DC origin to compensate for scrolling before drawing it (and then reset it back, of course), there is really no need to deal with events at all.

However if you really need to define a "post handler", then there is a way to do it, see [this blog post](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.fr/2013/01/about-benefits-of-procrastination.html). While the API described in it will only be available in wx 2.9.5, you do the same thing in the previous wx versions manually using `wxEVT_IDLE`.

Comment: The original problem was that once the background was drawn, wxWidgets would scroll it without calling my code to re-paint it; I was drawing it in the right place. `wxScrolledWindow::EnableScrolling` fixed that.

The new `CallAfter` thing sounds like it would have solved the problem too, the way I'd originally envisioned it. Thanks.